# Push and pop NavigationPage using dependency service

Tags: c#, ios, forms, xamarin, pushviewcontroller

I have a button created on PageRenderer:

```
        HomeLayout home = new HomeLayout();

protected override void OnElementChanged (VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged (e);
            var page = e.NewElement as HomeLayout;
            var view = NativeView;
            UIButton mybutton = new UIButton(...);
            [mybutton config]
            Add(mybutton);
        }
```

And I set a touch action to the button to open a forms view:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            mybutton.TouchUpInside += delegate {
            home.Navigation.PushAsync(new AnotherView(), true);
            };
        }
```

I can't see any error here... but the page don't open :s

Comment: Have you set breakpoints? How far does the code execute?

Comment: I can do it now... I create an event and it works!

Comment: That's great news! How did you fix it? If you can, leave an answer to your own question.